# awk parse filename and add result to the end of each line

Tags: bash, awk

I have number of files which have similar names like

```
DWH_Export_AUSTA_20120701_20120731_v1_1.csv.397.dat.2012-10-02 04-01-46.out
DWH_Export_AUSTA_20120701_20120731_v1_2.csv.397.dat.2012-10-02 04-03-12.out
DWH_Export_AUSTA_20120801_20120831_v1_1.csv.397.dat.2012-10-02 04-04-16.out
```

etc.

I need to get number before .csv(1 or 2) from the file name and put it into end of every line in file with TAB separator.

I have written this code, it finds number that I need, but i do not know how to put this number into file. There is space in the filename, my script breaks because of it.

Also I am not sure, how to send to script list of files. Now I am working only with one file.

My code:

```
#!/bin/sh
string="DWH_Export_AUSTA_20120701_20120731_v1_1.csv.397.dat.2012-10-02 04-01-46.out" 
out=$(echo $string | awk 'BEGIN {FS="_"};{print substr ($7,0,1)}')
awk ' { print $0"\t$out" } ' $string
```

Comment: Do you want to write the output back to the original file or just print it to stdout? The solutions for each will be a bit different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for file in *
do
   sfx=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/.*_\(.*\).csv.*/\1/')
   sed -i "s/$/\t$sfx/" "$file"
done
```

Comment: This script put "1" between CR and LF, so it appeared on the new line, not in the end of current line. any suggestions?

Comment: I used `tr` to trim CR. And your script worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*_\(.*\).csv.*/&\t\1/' file
DWH_Export_AUSTA_20120701_20120731_v1_1.csv.397.dat.2012-10-02 04-01-46.out     1
DWH_Export_AUSTA_20120701_20120731_v1_2.csv.397.dat.2012-10-02 04-03-12.out     2
DWH_Export_AUSTA_20120801_20120831_v1_1.csv.397.dat.2012-10-02 04-04-16.out     1
```

To make this for many files:

```
sed 's/.*_\(.*\).csv.*/&\t\1/' file1 file2 file3
```

OR

```
sed 's/.*_\(.*\).csv.*/&\t\1/' file*
```

To make this changed get saved in the same file(If you have GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/.*\(.\).csv.*/&\t\1/' file
```

Comment: You're assuming the number is only one digit in length. Try: `s/.*_\(.*\).csv.*/&\t\1/`

Comment: I'm actually re-reading some of the `awk` code (see the substring), you may have been right with your first answer: `s/.*\(.\).csv.*/&\t\1/`

Comment: This is the right solution. Exactly the kind of thing sed is good for :-)! +1

Comment: I spoke too soon, I thought the OP had files of lines to manipulate but apparently it's the file names he wants to extract the 1, 2, etc. from and then append those to the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this should do what you want (extract the number before .csv and append that number to the end of every line in the .out file)

```
awk 'FNR==1 { split(FILENAME, field, /[_.]/) } 
     { print $0"\t"field[7] > FILENAME"_aaaa" }' *.out

for file in *_aaaa; do mv "$file" "${file/_aaaa}"; done
```

Comment: The above awk script will append all of it's output a file named "FILENAME_aaaa". I think you meant `> FILENAME "_aaaa"  with just a single ">" and concatenating the variable with a string. I also think you're splitting FILENAME when you meant to split $0 but then why not just let FS do it's job?

Comment: Regarding `>>`, I wasn't sure if using `>` would keep overwriting the file with the most recent line. As for splitting FILENAME, that is intended because the number is obtained from the file name, not from lines inside the input files.

Comment: Oh, I misread the OP, I thought he had files containing lines like that. Anyway, no - the semantics for > are a bit different in awk than in shell. In awk > means create/zap the file when you first open it and append to it afterwards so it's like > in shell for the first output line but like >> in shell for subsequent output lines. In awk >> is just like >> in shell.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. `man` didn't say much about it so I just assumed the worst. Gonna fix up my answer.

Comment: while you're at it then, you could make your split a bit clearer and more idiomatic as `split(... /[_.]/)` rather than `split(... "_|\.")`. split() takes an RE as it's argument so you can use an RE constant rather than a dynamic RE and save having to worry about the two-parse issue. Also, `a|b` is used to create an or-separated list of REs but all you want to do is create a set of characters and the syntax for that is just `[ab]`.

Comment: Good call, `|` is way overkill for single characters. And good point about dynamic vs re constant.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to append the number from the filename to every line in that file - this should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ 0 < $# ]]; do
    num=$(echo "$1" | sed -r 's/.*_([0-9]+).csv.*/\t\1/' )
    #awk -e "{ print \$0\"\t${num}\"; }" < "$1" > "$1.new"
    #sed -r "s/$/\t$num/" < "$1" > "$1.mew"
    #sed -ri "s/$/\t$num/" "$1"
    shift
done
```

Run the script and give it names of the files you want to process. $# is the number of command line arguments for the script which is decremented at the end of the loop  by `shift`, which drops the first argument, and shifts the other ones. Extract the number from the filename and pick one of the three commented lines to do the appending: awk gives you more flexibility, first sed creates new files, second sed processes them in-place (in case you are running GNU sed, that is).

Comment: The comment says: "_pick one of the three commented lines to do the appending_" - just choose your preferred way to do it.

Comment: ou, ok. sorry, didn't catch it

Comment: No problem. :)
Thinking of it, I would probably suggest using the second one - `sed` should be faster than `awk` and if things go wrong, it will leave original the files untouched (you might want to pick a better suffix then the `.mew` I have used).

Comment: Good answer but why use while with a shift rather than a for loop on the arguments? By the way, you don't need -r on any but the first sed above and you don't need it there either if you use [0-9][0-9]* instead of [0-9]+ which would make it non GNU-specific. Finally, that is not one of the recommended ways to pass the value of shell variables to awk scripts.

Comment: GNU-specificity: I agree, but in most cases (imho) the sed in question is GNU and the extensions save some typing. As for passing the value - since it is only for printing it verbatim, it doesn't matter that much, but I agree that using `ENVIRON["num"]` is cleaner (but again: more typing).

Handling the command line options: I guess this is a habit. Parsing command line options in the form `--opt value` is usually easier with the while+shift construct than with a for loop.

Comment: I've tried this script with second sed, but got an error. `test.sh: 8: [[: not found`

Comment: try to replace the `[[ 0 < $#]]` with `test 0 -lt $#`. What shell are you using, by the way?

Alternatively, you can iterate over the command line parameters by using a for loop, e.g.: `for arg in "$@" ; do ... ; done`. Inside of the loop use `$arg` instead of `$1`.

Comment: @peterph - I wouldn't use ENVIRON["num"] either. Use `awk -v awkvar="$shellvar" '...' file` if possible, see Q24 in the comp.unix.shell FAQ, http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.

Comment: @EdMorton - hm, interestingly enough on Solaris none of the awk variants mentioned seem to support option e) (or the FAQ has a typo).

Comment: No typo, it's correct. See note 9 in that FAQ for what "e" is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of awk, you may want to go with sed or coreutils.

Grab number from filename, with grep for variety:

```
num=$(<<<filename grep -Eo '[^_]+\.csv' | cut -d. -f1)
```

`<<<filename` is equivalent to `echo filename`.

#### With sed

Append `num` to each line with GNU sed:

```
sed "s/\$/\t$num" filename
```

Use the `-i` switch to modify `filename` in-place.

#### With paste

You also need to know the length of the file for this method:

```
len=$(<filename wc -l)
```

Combine `filename` and `num` with paste:

```
paste filename <(seq $len | while read; do echo $num; done)
```

#### Complete example

```
for filename in DWH_Export*; do 
  num=$(echo $filename | grep -Eo '[^_]+\.csv' | cut -d. -f1)
  sed -i "s/\$/\t$num" $filename
done
```

Comment: `test.sh: 3: Syntax error: redirection unexpected` I get this error with complete example

Comment: @erizo: bash seems to have issues with the `<<<` notation, I've changed it to `echo`.